# Are the effects of the awaken spell permanent?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Could you have a druid being followed by any number of [awakened](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/awaken) creatures permanently (assuming their relationship is a good one, and the creatures want to follow the druid)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolutely.  In fact, the duration of the spell is *instantaneous*, which means that it can't be dispelled once it has taken effect.  If a druid is good enough at convincing animals to follow them, they can have as many intelligent followers as they want.

This is no different from the rules for getting regular people to follow you.  If you have a paladin or a bard who can convince normal folks to follow them, they can do that all they want.  Remember that these new intelligent creatures are *sentient*, and now have their own wants and desires.  The relevant quote is:

> You have no special empathy or connection with a creature you awaken, although it serves you in specific tasks or endeavors if you communicate your desires to it. If you cast awaken again, any previously awakened creatures remain friendly to you, but they no longer undertake tasks for you unless it is in their best interests.

So you can have one awakened creature that will help you for a while, but if you want more, it will take no less effort to get them to stay with you than it would to get people to follow you.

Comment: Very helpful!  One thing that remains unclear is the spell states "To succeed, you must make a Will save (DC 10 + the animal's current HD, or the HD the tree will have once awakened)."  Does this mean that for the spell to work the caster has to make a will save?  Seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: It's definitely strange, but it looks like that's what the spell says.

Comment: Another strange fact: "Casting Time: 24 hours" "Range: touch" uuh... so I have to touch it during the whole time, or just at the end of the 24h? What if it's no longer there, how much time do I have before the spell expires? Maybe this is covered by a generic rule, but I never encountered such a thing so far.

Comment: You touch it at the end of the casting, like you would with any touch spell.  Think of how Cure Light Wounds works.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, the effects of Awaken are Permanent

The spell awaken has a duration of instantaneous, which I'll quote the effects of here.

> **Instantaneous**
>
> The spell energy comes and goes the instant the spell is cast, though the consequences might be long-lasting.

In the case of Awaken, the spell doesn't make sense with that duration if the effects aren't permanent.

## For Followers, it's Unclear

There's nothing in the rules that prohibits having a procession of hired help, followers, or talking animals follow you.  However, this sort of thing is usually handled with the Leadership feat, which the GM might require for a large number of devoted followers.  Ultimately, this one is up to the GM.

Comment: I'm glad you brought up Leadership because I was thinking, where Leadership would make certain people be VERY willing to take commands from you, simply talking people (or awakened creatures) to take commands from you may be tougher but still doable.  So where Leadership can let you have loyal followers under your banner, certain people or creatures may still be persuaded to come with you on adventures even without the feat if the conditions are right.